# Single file for multiple WSDL binding

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am currently developing SOAP webservices client using Apache CXF's cxf-codegen-plugin. Since I have multiple WSDL, I need to bind it to different packages in my java project.

My question is, is it possible to define 1 single binding file for multiple WSDL file?

Below is my plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>src/main/resources/wsdl/bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                </defaultOptions>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlRoot>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this but to no avail

```
<jaxws:bindings
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">

    <jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="serviceA.wsdl" >
        <jaxws:package name="org.ws.serviceA"/>
    </jaxws:bindings>

    <jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="serviceB.wsdl" >
        <jaxws:package name="org.ws.serviceB"/>
    </jaxws:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it is indeed impossible and clearly stated in this site

https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html

> 1.1.1 Root Binding Element
>
> The jaxws:bindings declaration appears as the root of all other
>   binding declarations. This top-level jaxws:bindings element **must**
>   specify the location of the WSDL file as a URI in the value of
>   wsdlLocation attribute.

However it did not specify anything about the wsdlLocation at child element. This site does http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203Y2310e/EY230286.HTM#ID00669

> **Non-root jaxws:bindings** > wsdlLocation > The attribute **cannot** be
>   specified. Even if the attribute is specified, it is ignored.

Hopefully this can be improved in the future as JAXB can already bind multiple schemaLocation in one file like this

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" node="//xsd:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="org.package1" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>


    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema2.xsd" node="//xsd:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="org.package2" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```